# AlamofireImage: Can't get image in completion block from af_setImageWithURL

Tags: ios, alamofireimage

all

I am learning Swift and I am trying to set an image on a UIImageView using AlamofireImage. I am using the following code:

```
self.listImageView.af_setImageWithURL(
        NSURL(string: list!.image!)!,
        placeholderImage: nil,
        filter: nil,
        imageTransition: .CrossDissolve(0.5),
        completion:{ image in
            print(image)
        }
)
```

and the result in the console is the following:

```
SUCCESS: <UIImage: 0x7fb0c3ec3d30>, {512, 286}
```

My objective is to do something with the image once is downloaded, but the problem is that I don't understand the signature for the completion callback and I don't know how to access to the image in the completion block. According to the documentation, is `Result<UIImage, NSError>`.

I guess is something really simple, but I am not realizing it.

Thanks

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `image` variable passed into the completion block is actually [`Alamofire.Response`](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Response.swift#L28) type, not the underlying `UIImage` instance itself that was fetched.

You need to update your completion block like below in order to get the actual image from the response:

```
self.listImageView.af_setImage(
    withURL: URL(string: list!.image!)!,
    placeholderImage: nil,
    filter: nil,
    imageTransition: .crossDissolve(0.5),
    completion: { response in
        print(response.value) # UIImage
        print(response.error) # NSError
    }
)
```

You might first want to check `response.result.isSuccess` (or his brother `response.result.isFailure`) to make sure whether the image has been successfully retrieved or not.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I needed, but I have to say that the response it's not very friendly to figure that out :)

Comment: great . This helped me very much in my chat application.